# Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - .yardoc/processing

Tags: ruby, yard

```
aleksiares@unit:~/wasteland/sokol_dev$ yard
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/core_ext/file.rb:56:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - .yardoc/processing (Errno::EACCES)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/core_ext/file.rb:56:in `open'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/core_ext/file.rb:56:in `open!'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/serializers/yardoc_serializer.rb:52:in `lock_for_writing' from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/registry_store.rb:197:in `lock_for_writing'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/registry.rb:208:in `lock_for_writing'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/yardoc.rb:251:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/command.rb:13:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/command_parser.rb:71:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/command_parser.rb:53:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/bin/yard:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/yard:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/yard:23:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Hello, have a problem with self-documenting code, there is no concept of what comes out of error, can help possible.

Comment: did you by chance run `sudo gem install`? this isn't a good way to do it.

Comment: Yes, well established, and better through Gamefile and bundle installs?

Comment: Yeah. Try bundle install then bundle exec yard

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your current user has no read or write access to the `.yardoc/processing` file in the current directory.

Yard uses these files to signal other tools that yard is in use and thus must be able to write there. Please check your file permissions and ensure that your current user is able to wrote to this directory.

Comment: It seems to give access to the catalog, the result was to issue the following:

Comment: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in on_params': undefined method `type' for 69048:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
And further errors like "usr/local/rvm/gems..."